# How to set global/system config to all users and profiles for Firefox?

Tags: 22.04, firefox

Firefox on Ubuntu picks up configs from config file under `~/.mozilla/firefox/cx3a9c6c.default-release/`, but this path is specific to a user and to a specific profile (the path even has a hash).

Does firefox have a path where it loads system default settings from?

The goal is to distribute "Disable hardware accelerated graphics" to all machines and users in my workplace, using probably these settings:

```
user_pref("browser.preferences.defaultPerformanceSettings.enabled", false);
user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
```

Is there any difference depending on snap/.deb installation?